# Blazor WASM cannot inject my service on razor component

Tags: razor, dependency-injection, blazor, webassembly

I have an Interface created in a folder Services on the server side of my Blazor WASM.
I registered it in program.cs, server side: builder.Services.AddScoped<IUpdateGui, UpdateGui>();

Now when I want to @inject it at my razor component (client side) it cannot find my service.
What am I doing wrong? I am trying to achive that I can subscribe to the event on my razor page.

Interface:

```
public interface IUpdateGui
    {
        public event EventHandler UpdateGuiEvent;

        public void UpdateGuiClass()
        {

        }
    }
```

My class

```
public class UpdateGui : IUpdateGui
    {
        public event EventHandler UpdateGuiEvent;

        public void UpdateGuiClass()
        {
            UpdateGuiEvent?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
```

Program.cs (server side)

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUpdateGui, UpdateGui>();
```

Razor (not working part (The type of namespace could not be found)

```
@inject IUpdateGui _updateGui
```

Comment: DotNet Version and the RenderMode setup of your application/components?  Since Net8 release this is important information!

Comment: .net version 6 .

Comment: Add the namespace to `_Imports.razor`??

Comment: I cant add the namespace to import.razor The server is not addable

Comment: Your `IUpdateGui` is in a project and has a namespace.  Where is it and what is it?  Program can obviously see it.  Where is your component?  project and namespace.  At the moment your question doesn't have enough information to provide an answer.

Comment: "The server is not addable" makes no sense.

Comment: Did you add this `builder.Services.AddScoped<IUpdateGui, UpdateGui>();` in your client's `Program.cs`?

Comment: Hi Marius, yes I registered the service like that